# Copy attributes from one feature to empty row of another feature in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, attribute-table, editing

How do you copy all of the non-geometry attribute data from one feature to another "empty" feature? For example, how would I copy all of the non-geometry attribute data from the "Seattle Mariners" polygon to the empty Alaska polygon? Using copy/paste pastes both the attributes *and* the geometry. I do not want to copy the geometry. Just the non-geometry attributes.

[Here are instructions](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/editing-attributes/copying-and-pasting-attribute-values.htm) for how to do this in ArcMap. Is there a similar "copy attributes" option in QGIS?

[image]

Comment: @Taras I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you mean?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, there is. It's the 'Merge Attributes of Selected Features' button.

1. First you need to enable the Advanced Digitising toolbar (**View > Toolbars > Advanced Digitising**).
2. Then enable editing on your desired layer and select **both** the feature you want to copy attributes from, and **any** of the feature(s) you want to copy attributes to.

[image]

3. In the main window the Merge Attributes of Selected Features button will now activate.

[image]

4. Now you see your features listed by ID and get the option to decide what attributes get copied over, from which feature. In your case,

   - select the feature you want to copy *from*, (here it is feature 0) by clicking on the row
   - click "Take attributes from selected feature"
   - scroll across to confirm that you want that attribute across all fields - maybe there is an ID field you don't want copied over. In this example I don't want `treeid` to be copied over, so I left that as Skip attribute, but everything else will copy the values from Feature 0.

[image]

5. Click OK and check your attribute table. The values should have copied over now.
   Note `treeid` is null because I specified that in the previous step.
   [image]

Comment: You are an absolute godsend. I cannot thank you enough for such a clear and detailed answer. One place I kept going wrong was that I kept clicking on "Advanced Digitizing panel" and not "Advanced Digitizing toolbar." I got tunnel vision and couldn't see that there was both a panel and a toolbar, which turn out to be quite different. Thank you again.

Comment: Yes, it's really quite confusing. They ought to call the Advanced Digitizing Panel "CAD Digitising" or something like that. The Advanced Digitising toolbar has certainly expanded over time; I only discovered Merge Attributes just two weeks ago myself.

Comment: Agreed. I kept yelling at my computer, "but I'm not trying to use CAD tools!" lol