# Merge attributes of selected features not working in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis-3, attribute-table, attribute-joins

The following option in the advanced digitizing toolbar: Merge attributes with following features is not working.

According to the following query:

[Copy attributes from one feature to empty row of another feature in QGIS 3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/357189/copy-attributes-from-one-feature-to-empty-row-of-another-feature-in-qgis-3)

I tried to follow this way, but it simply doesn't work in my case.

[image]

I am getting nothing in my column after confirming (clicking "Take attributes from selected feature") and clicking OK.

[image]

I want the bounded columns in another data attribute table.

How can I use this tool properly?

Is it driven my the following bug described here?

https://issues.qgis.org/issues/11409

https://issues.qgis.org/issues/11405

Comment: I may be mistaken but it looks like you are trying to add fields and attributes from one layer to another.  The merge attributes tool works on features in the same layer being edited.  To add the fields from one layer to another you could use the Refactor Fields tool template.  If you can run a join (by matching attributes or spatial) you could add the fields and attributes from one layer to another.

Comment: yes, you are right. However when I had the same issue with exactly the same tables:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/374849/merging-attributes-of-selected-features-tool-not-working-in-qgis-3